# Angular and NGXS labs actions executing: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ngxs

Here is my repo: https://github.com/richarddavenport/why

I am unable to reproduce this issue on stackblitz.com or codesandbox.io.

I'm getting the dreaded error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?
```

My child component view:

```html
<div>{{fetching$ | async | json}}</div>
<form [formGroup]="form" ngxsForm="state.form"></form>
```

My Action handler in state:

```
  @Action(FetchAction)
  fetchAction() {
    console.log('Dispatched --> fetch');

    return of(true).pipe(delay(15000));
  }
```

If you change the `delay()` to 0 like this, there is no error:

```
  @Action(FetchAction)
  fetchAction() {
    console.log('Dispatched --> fetch');

    return of(true).pipe(delay(0));
  }
```

If you remove the form from child component view, there is no error:

```html
<div>{{fetching$ | async | json}}</div>
```

There are actions that dispatch from the `ngxsForm` directive to initially sync up the state, but I can't tell if they are causing the problem or not.

Comment: im not familiar with ngxsForm but you could probably fix it with changing component's change detection strategy or manually detecting changes after the delay with https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: :facepalm: Thanks @ihorbond, you're right. Using onPush for the change detection does prevent that error.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the components change detection to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` fixes this issue.